# Why is the following code of ASP.NET not working?

Tags: asp.net

I have just started learning ASP.NET. While going through a few tutorials I came across this example-
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showfile_c.asp?filename=try_webpages_cs_001
When I wrote the same code in visual studio 2012, I am not getting the output as mentioned in the tutorial, instead the output is

> The time is @DateTime.Now

What am I doing wrong here? I am completely new to ASP.NET and don't have even slightest idea of the language, although I know a bit of C# and Python.

Comment: bcz that is classic asp and u are working on asp .net

Comment: You're probably using the WebForms view engine which doesn't support Razor syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
  The time is <%=DateTime.Now %>
```

That should write the timestamp into the response.